# Alternative to multiple promises for slideshow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a loop that creates a slideshow with ui-router. It is working properly, but I don't think it's the way to go. Can anyone provide an alternative to declaring so many promises?

```
define(['./module'], function (controllers) {
  controllers.controller('homeController', function($timeout, $state, $scope) {

  var promise;
  promise = $timeout(function slide() {
    $state.transitionTo('home.construcao');
       promise1 = $timeout(function () {
          $state.transitionTo('home.saude');
       }, 3000);

       promise2 = $timeout(function () {
          $state.transitionTo('home.business');
       }, 5000);

       promise3 = $timeout(function () {
          $state.transitionTo('home.premium');
       }, 7000);
       promise4 = $timeout(slide, 9000);
  }, 0);
  $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
    $timeout.cancel(promise1);
    $timeout.cancel(promise2);
    $timeout.cancel(promise3);
    $timeout.cancel(promise4);
    console.log(promise);
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Sorry I edit the question. Now is correct, I want to know if there is a way to declare only one variable instead of promise, promise1, etc..

Comment: This cancels the timeout loop when location/route change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in fact you don't need to nest multiple promises inside another as you have in your sample code.

Just reuse one variable for all promises. Then, when you need to cancel it, call `$timeout.cancel` passing that promise variable as the parameter:

```
// slide objects contain state labels plus amount of time each slide will
// appear for
var slides = [ 
   {state: 'home.construcao', time: 3000},
   {state: 'home.saude', time: 2000},
   {state: 'home.business', time: 2000},
   {state: 'home.premium', time: 2000}
];

var index = 0; // initialize index (start with first slide)
var promise; // set var here so it's available in scope for $timeout.cancel later

// assign anonymous function to named var so it can be referenced by $timeout
var slide = function(){ 
   // show slide, accessing state label string from array
   $state.transitionTo(slides[index].state); 
   // call $timeout to recursively call this function, which will show next slide
   promise = $timeout(slide, slides[index].time);
   // if at the last value in the slide array, reset back to the first for
   // next slide to be shown
   index = (index < slides.length - 1) ? index + 1 : 0;
};

slide(); // start slideshow

$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
   // interrupt $timeout when event fires; pause slideshow
   $timeout.cancel(promise); 
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DULv49Z3wIrXve99hwYV?p=preview)

Comment: Nice! I'll try this out!

Comment: Can you comment the lines in the way I can understand the logic? Thank you in advance

Comment: Updated with comments. Hope they help.